# spark worker with 32GB or more memory encountered a fatal error

Tags: apache-spark, join, memory, fatal-error

I have three slaves in a standalone Spark Cluster. Each slave has 48GB of RAM. When I assigned more than 31GB (e.g. 32GB or more) of RAM to my executors:

```
.config("spark.executor.memory", "44g")
```

the executors were terminated without much information during a join of two large Dataframes. The output message at the Slave driver showed "missing an output location for shuffle":

```
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20170921123240-0000/3 on hostPort XXX.XXX.XXX.92:33705 with 6 cores, 44.0 GB RAM
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 124, XXX.XXX.XXX.92, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 115, XXX.XXX.XXX.92, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 17.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 127, XXX.XXX.XXX.92, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 118, XXX.XXX.XXX.92, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 112, XXX.XXX.XXX.92, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 121, XXX.XXX.XXX.92, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 0 (epoch 5)
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 0 requested
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_10_2 !
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_10_11 !
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170921123240-0000/3 is now RUNNING
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_10_5 !
17/09/21 12:34:18 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_10_8 !
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(0, XXX.XXX.XXX, 34840, None)
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 0 successfully in removeExecutor
```

The log message of Spark Master showed that the executors were "EXITED" and then relaunched:

```
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20170921123240-0000/0 because it is EXITED
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20170921123240-0000/3 on worker worker-20170921123014-152.83.247.92-33705
```

The log message of Spark Worker showed that the executor exited with code 134

```
17/09/21 12:34:18 INFO Worker: Executor app-20170921123240-0000/0 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 134 exitStatus 134
```

The only clue seems to be in the error log of the application, showing a fatal error has been detected by the JRE:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdec0c92a73, pid=11300, tid=0x00007fd3a6951700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x3ffa73]  CardTableExtension::scavenge_contents_parallel(ObjectStartArray*, MutableSpace*, HeapWord*, PSPromotionManager*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x5e3
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000001c9e800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x00007fd3a6851000,0x00007fd3a6952000] [id=11308]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000008
```

As long as I assign 31GB of RAM (or less) to each executor, my program works just fine. Has anyone encountered such problem before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

44 GB may actually give you a smaller usable heap than 31 GB due to how Java stores object references: For heap sizes over 32 GB the JVM has to switch to 64 bit object references, which means all objects take up more space. More details here: http://java-performance.info/over-32g-heap-java/

My rule of thumb is to either stay below 32 GB or go much higher (say, 50 GB). Usually it is more cost efficient to use multiple JVMs, each having less than 32 GB heap. With 48 GB RAM I would stick to 31 GB heap.